# Double click to expand custom dropdown list on Angular 1.2.x

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I used this [custom Drop-Down list guide](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/) to create on Angular 1.0.7 a fancy `dropdown list` that will be supported on all browsers.
Everything worked fine as you can see in this [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/TBrlW2kU5oi0xDkEZPe3?p=preview).

Then I decided to upgrade to Angular 1.2.x.
On the new angular it seems that always on first run the first click is not expanding
the `drop-down` `list`.
After I double click the `drop-down` then it is working normally again like Angular 1.0.7

Example - [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/4ZzZKdSiPJ5wMyQ1IyhC?p=preview)

How can I make my `drop-down` `list` on Angular 1.2.x expand on first click instead of double click on my `application` first run?

My HTML:

```
  <body ng-controller="VotesCtrl">
    <p>This is from index.html</p>
    <div dropdown="" class="{{temp}} wrapper-dropdown-3" ng-click="temp='active'">
      <i class="arrow"></i>
      <span>{{selected}}</span>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li ng-repeat="status in statuses">
          <a ng-click="change(status)" href="#">{{status}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
```

My JS:

```
var webApp = angular.module('webApp', []);


//controllers

webApp.controller ('VotesCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.statuses = ["Approved","Pending","Trash","Spam"];
    $scope.selected = $scope.statuses[0];  

    $scope.change = function(status) {
       console.log(status);
       $scope.selected = status;     
    };
});


webApp.controller ('tempCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.statuses = ["Approved","Pending","Trash","Spam"];
    $scope.selected = $scope.statuses[0];  

    $scope.change = function(status) {
       $scope.selected = status;     
    };
});
//services



//directive

webApp.directive('dropdown', function() {
    angular.element(document).click(function() {
      // all dropdowns
      angular.element('.wrapper-dropdown-3').removeClass('active');
    });  
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

          // var dd = new DropDown(elem);
          angular.element(elem).on('click', function(event) {
            angular.element(this).toggleClass('active');
            return false;
        });
      }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the 

`click="temp='active'"`
 
your code should work again with the first click